# Linux command to check zip file hierarchy

Tags: linux, zip

Is there a good linux command that can show the file hierarchy of zipped directory?

If I open a zip file with emacs, I can see it. But I guess there is a appropriate command for that purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to something like a tree structure? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-directory-structure-command-line/

Comment: Just list up the file names is enough for me.

Comment: Oh to show everything in that zip file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `less` utility is capable of peeking into a zip archive. In fact, if you look at the outputs of `unzip -l zipfile` and `less zipfile`, you will find them to be identical.

Comment: thank you. `unzip -l` works as I need. (but less doesn't work)

Comment: Note, that less zipfile on MacOS-X displays the binary filecontent, so you see a lot of garbage instead of the content of the zip-file. Then you should opt for the ``ùnzip -l zipfile```